# Set of generators of a $R$-algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

In my algebra textbook I came across the following:

> Let $A$ be a $R$-algebra ($R$ is a commutative ring with unity $1_R$)
>   and suppose $X\subseteq A$ a generator set for $A$.

In this context, what does a generator set for $A$ mean? Does it mean $A$ is generated by $X$ as a $R$-module?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be ambiguous, but I would usually parse it as a set of generators as an $R$-algebra, i.e. that every element of $A$ can be written as a polynomial in the elements of $X$ with coefficients in $R$.

For instance, $\{x\}$ generates $\Bbb Z[x]$ as a $\Bbb Z$-algebra, whereas you would need something like $\{1, x, x^2, \ldots \}$ to get a set of generators as a $\Bbb Z$-module.